# Imrpove drainage

Tags: drain, drainage

[image: j]

[image]

[image]

We have a negetive slope driveway, it has a dry well right in front of the garage door with a big drain cover, every time it rains heavily, water flows into garage, due to unevenness of the floor, water is finding its way even after putting floor threshold and garage door bottom seal.

Today I started digging the dry well and it's filled with mud and stones (photo #3).

How can I improve drainage, currently if I put water on it (photo #1), it doesn't flow freely and water stands for quite a while.

Should I dig out all the mud and stone, and fill it with some kind or drainage stones?

Comment: Ordinarily I would expect that to be a drain, with a pipe that goes *somewhere.*  If you're sure about that being a dry well, your only solution is to make the gravel reservoir bigger.  You should also wrap the reservoir in geotextile, so that you can keep the fines from runoff (and the surrounding soil) out of it (slop it out perioodically).